# What refund am I entitled to from BA if I first accept a change of itinerary

Tags: covid-19, cancellations, british-airways

I paid EUR 670 for flights in August (VIE-LHR). First the outbound flight was cancelled, so I rebooked it (at no cost) for the next day. Now all the flights have been cancelled and I want a cash refund, but BA are only offering me EUR 393 (through their website). I assume they want to refund only the cheaper ticket I rebooked for the outward leg (plus the original return leg) – but I've still spent EUR 670 and they've cancelled my flights, so am I entitled to the full amount, and how would I go about holding them to it?

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: For clarity, the new outbound flight you changed to was cheaper than the original, but the difference wasn’t refunded to you / no other compensation was given at that time?

Comment: I’m guessing it was cheaper, but wasn’t shown a price. Certainly I wasn’t given refund at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's tricky since this specific case isn't covered in the EU261 regulations.

BA will likely drag their feet: on the first cancellation, you got rebooked to a cheaper ticket. On the second cancellation, you are offered a refund on the ticket that got cancelled.

I would try the following angles with the BA representative:

1. If it's still the same booking reference number, than it's still the original booking with the price you paid and that's the refund owed. This argument doesn't hold if the rebooking generated a new booking with a new PNR.
2. If your changed flight would have been more expensive, would they refund the higher price or just the original money paid?
3. Per EU261 you are owed a refund of the money you paid. EU216 states in Article 8

> - reimbursement within seven days, by the means provided for in Article 7(3), of the full cost of the ticket at the price at which it was bought

See https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261

If they cancelled less than 14 days before departure you are also owed additional compensation.

Comment: They dragged their feet a bit, but after a couple of phone calls and Twitter DMs I got my refund. I definitely get the sense that they wanted me to take their first offer and go away.